# Retrieving params from url with c# and angular

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, typescript

I am having issues retrieving parameters from my URL that is an API. Any
help would be greatly appreciated.

## Here is my c# code

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
   public class PasswordController : Controller
   {
       private readonly AppSettings _options;

       public PasswordController(IOptions<AppSettings> optionsAccessor)
       {
           _options = optionsAccessor.Value;

       }

       [HttpGet]
       //this isnt returning anything...
       public IActionResult Get([FromQuery]string emp)
       {
           var x = HttpContext.Request.Query["emp"].ToString();
               Response.Headers.Add("x-emp-name", x);

           return Json(_options.ClientSettings);
       }
```

## Here is my angular code ts

```
 private GetData(): void {
     this.http.get('api/password').subscribe(values => {
     this.ViewOptions = values.json();
     this.titleService.setTitle(this.ViewOptions.changePasswordTitle + " -
" + this.ViewOptions.applicationTitle);
     if (this.ViewOptions.recaptcha.isEnabled) {
       this.FormGroup.addControl('reCaptcha', new FormControl('',
[Validators.required]));
       const sp = document.createElement('script');
       sp.type = 'text/javascript';
       sp.async = true;
       sp.defer = true;
       sp.src =
'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=vcRecaptchaApiLoaded&render=explicit&hl='
+ this.ViewOptions.recaptcha.languageCode;
     }
   });
 }
```

Here is my browser console screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Your URL also doesn't look correct. It should (?) be something like  `api/password?emp=`

Comment: Thanks for the comment how would I had a var param to the url in my angular code? @MarkC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a parameter into your method:

```
 private GetData(queryParam): void {
     this.http.get('api/password?emp=' + queryParam).subscribe(values => {
     this.ViewOptions = values.json();
 ///code omitted
```

note: I don't know the exact syntax for TypeScript parameters so this probably isn't copy/paste-able.

Answer (score 1):

So as I understand your question, you try to call the api/password endpoint with the get parameter `?emp=Test` from within an angular web app.

As I see you don't call the endpoint with the parameter but call the whole angular app with the parameter. So my suggestion was to call

```
this.http.get('api/password?emp=Test').subscribe
```

from the typescript code.

Comment: How would I call this with a variable because the param wouln't always be "Test"? Thanks for you answer btw @Corristo

Comment: did your controller receive "Test" in the emp param?
If yes pls mark my answer as correct cause this was what the question was about. As Mark C. wrote with `this.http.get('api/password?emp=' + param)` you can build your request url with JS variables.